# When did Batman become a vampire?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification, vampire

I remember a long time ago (in the 80's), my Batman comics took a cool turn... he turned into a vampire.  This story ran for a while, but I can't find any info on it.  I see there were a few other books, but those aren't what I'm looking for.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 13):

*[Batman and Dracula: Red Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Dracula_trilogy#Red_Rain_.281991.29)*

A female vampire bites Batman to make him powerful enough to help take down Dracula. It's a graphic novel from 1991.

There's also *The Batman and Dracula Trilogy*, a collection of this work and its two sequel runs.

Comment: Red Rain is just plain wrong answer in this case. I am also looking more info about the story OP is talking about.
This has nothing to do with Dracula and to the best of my memory it is a story arc involving Dick Grayson's new girlfriend who turns out to be vampire along with her brother (they were turned by snake bite). And yes, Batman does turn into a vampire after being bitten and almost kills Alfred. To my understanding it was published in late 70's or early 80's. I'd like to know the actual issues and the total length of the story... the climax lasted maybe 4-5 issues. EDIT: I managed to

Answer (score 2):

## What Stalks the Gotham Night?

I think I found it - I was looking for the same one, so I did some searching and came up with this:
https://babblingsaboutdccomics4.wordpress.com/tag/dick-grayson/page/2/
The image of the comic is here, and it's the one I remember reading:

[image: Cover shot]
[image: Fighting the vampires]

Answer (score 1):

#### The comic run you may be referring to is "The 'I' of the Beholder" - Detective Comics #511-515 (1982). In this issue Batman and Robin meet the vampire [Dala](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dala_Vadim_(New_Earth)) who was an ally to the Golden Age vampire called [The Monk](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Niccolai_Tepes_(New_Earth)).

[image]

> - The Monk returned several decades later when writer Gerry Conway revived him in 1982's Detective Comics #515. The Monk's appearance is preceded by Dala's return in Detective Comics #511, during which she romances Dick Grayson (a.k.a. Robin) as part of her master's plan.
> - Conway's story is ostensibly an update of the original tale, establishing an Earth-One counterpart of the Monk during the days of DC Comics' Multiverse. It departs from the original, however, by establishing the Monk's true identity and origin. In Conway's version, the Monk is a post-Civil War plantation owner in New Orleans named Louis DuBois. He and his sister Dala are attacked by their vengeful ex-slaves and subjected to a voodoo ritual which transforms them into the undead.
> - During the course of the story, Batman himself is transformed into a vampire by the Monk but is eventually cured by a serum administered by a priest/exorcist named Father Green. At the conclusion of the tale, Green departed with the captive Monk and Dala, hinting that he had been pursuing them for a very long time indeed.