# Has Batman ever fought Hawkman?

Tags: dc, batman

My children are going through a comic that they just got today in the mail and it has a 'Tourney' set up to find out who the best villain and superhero is and then who would win in the fight. The first matchup is "Hawkman vs. Batman".

I like Batman (so I am biased) but **are there any instances in which they have actually fought each other, and if so, who won?**

Comment: As an aside, Batman was apparently [inspired](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122332/was-the-idea-of-batman-inspired-by-vampires/122582#122582) in part by the Hawkmen in the *Flash Gordon* comic strips.

Comment: Are we going to find out who won then? Or did the magazine just raise the matchup as a thought experiment?

Comment: @Richard, I am thinking that I might post the entire tournament and ask make it similar in structure to this question,  your thoughts?

Comment: @Richard ►►►►http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9457/25784

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** - **If Hawkman fought Batman in a stand-up fight, he would defeat Batman with relative ease.** In addition to being stronger, possessing regenerative powers, greater speed and the ability to fly, he also has a wide range of lethal weaponry.

The standard response to this argument is that if Batman *knew a fight was coming*, there's really no-one he can't defeat, up to and including Superman.

---

Batman fought Hawkman in [JLA #119](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/JLA:_Crisis_of_Conscience) as part of the "Crisis of Conscience" story arc. Since Batman was under Despero's mind-control, Hawkman wasn't looking to kill him but merely subdue him. Batman ended up slugging him and Hawkman backed off. Despite taking a **solid punch right in the face from Batman**, on the following page Hawkman seems quite well, albeit rubbing his jaw.

[image]

They also fought (briefly) in Public Enemies. Again, Hawkman has a substantial advantage, trapping Batman in a thrown web but doesn't move in for the kill, ultimately losing when Superman steps in.

Comment: That video needs more abs.